# Chinese freelancers without a VAT number working for European companies

Tags: european-union, tax-law, china

When a European company hires the services of a Chinese entity,
can that Chinese entity be an individual without a company or VAT number?

Or simply put, are there laws or regulations in China that allow individuals to do business with foreign companies without that individual having a company number or VAT number?

And finally, should that European company care about the lack of a VAT number on its received invoices?

Comment: The company actually imports Chinese goods and services. So it makes sense for it to deal with Chinese companies. Some individuals reach out to work for that company. Because they don't have the usual expected legal documents, it appears that they may be individuals that just try to evade taxes. However, they sometimes claim that they are allowed to work without a VAT number because their revenue is rather low. Of course, it is hard to verify if this is the truth.

Comment: "are there laws or regulations in China that allow individuals to do business with foreign companies without that individual having a company number or VAT number?" Chinese VAT or destination European VAT? China would usually have laws on its own VAT but not on the VAT of the European country someone there does business with.

Comment: Is the concern that the European firm would have liability to Chinese tax collectors for conspiring to violate Chinese tax laws?